How to remove motion blur from a given image in frequency domain (deconvolution)?
I have read that if we have the PSF of a given image, using deconvolution we can reverse the distortion and get the original image. I tried to do the same thing, however, I'm getting an image that looks like complete noise:
def add_motion_blur(img, size=31, angle=11):
    kernel = np.zeros((size,size), dtype=np.float32)
    # set the middle row of the kernel array to be all ones. 
    kernel[size//2,:] = np.ones((size,),dtype=np.float32)
    # now rotate the kernel
    m = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((size//2, size//2), angle=angle, scale=1.0)
    kernel = cv2.warpAffine(kernel, m, dsize=(size,size))
    kernel /= np.sum(kernel)
    return cv2.filter2D(img, ddepth=-1, kernel=kernel), kernel

img = cv2.imread('./img/peppers.jpg')
# adding motion blur is akin to creating the PSF because 
# it's a distorting operator, and we are distorting the image using it!
img_blurred, kernel = add_motion_blur(img, size=31, angle=60)
# now we should be able to deconvolve the image with the PSF and get the deblurred version 
# for this we can use the fourier transform and divide our blurred image from the psf
fft = np.fft.fftn(img_blurred[...,0])
# pad the kernel so its the same shape as our image so the division goes on without an issue
fft_psf = np.fft.fftn(kernel, s=fft.shape)
fft_result = fft/fft_psf
ifft_result = np.fft.ifft2(fft_result)
deblurred_image = np.abs(ifft_result).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imshow('deblurred image',deblurred_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

This results in pure noise it seems:

I also tried Wiener deconvolution to no avail:
# Wiener deconvolution
fft_psf_mag = np.conj(fft_psf) / (np.abs(fft_psf)**2 + 10)
fft_result = fft / fft_psf_mag

It results in the same result it seems:

What am I missing here? I also tried fft/(fft_psf+1e-3) as a way of regularizing the kernel's small values, but this does not result in any improvement either.
Side note
These are the previous outputs belonging to the original image, the blurred version and the kernel used:



Update:
Here is the updated version which:

pads the kernel properly on all sides
the imaginary values are close to 0
However the problem still persists and I can not get anything meaningful! The outputs are given at the end:

def add_motion_blur(img, size=31, angle=11):
    kernel = np.zeros((size,size), dtype=np.float32)
    # set the middle row of the kernel array to be all ones. 
    kernel[size//2,:] = np.ones((size,),dtype=np.float32)
    # now rotate the kernel
    m = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((size//2, size//2), angle=angle, scale=1.0)
    kernel = cv2.warpAffine(kernel, m, dsize=(size,size))
    kernel /= np.sum(kernel)
    return cv2.filter2D(img, ddepth=-1, kernel=kernel), kernel

img = cv2.imread('./img/peppers.jpg')
# adding motion blur is akin to creating the PSF because 
# it's a distorting operator, and we are distorting the image using it!
img_blurred, kernel = add_motion_blur(img, size=31, angle=60)
# now we should be able to deconvolve the image with the PSF and get the deblurred version 
# for this we can use the fourier transform and divide our blurred image from the psf
fft = np.fft.fftn(img_blurred[...,0])
# pad the kernel equally on all sides, so that it sits at the center!
pad_height = img.shape[0] - kernel.shape[0]
pad_width = img.shape[1] - kernel.shape[1]
pad_top = pad_height // 2
pad_bottom = pad_height - pad_top
pad_left = pad_width // 2
pad_right = pad_width - pad_left
kernel_padded = np.pad(kernel, [(pad_top, pad_bottom), (pad_left, pad_right)], 'constant')
fft_psf = np.fft.fft2(kernel_padded)
# the normal way doesnt work!
# fft_result = fft/fft_psf
# wiener deconvolution (0.8 is the best I could find to get something that could be visualized somewhat properly)
fft_psf_mag = np.conj(fft_psf) / (np.abs(fft_psf)**2 + 0.8)
fft_result = fft * fft_psf_mag
# get back the image
ifft_result = np.fft.ifft2(fft_result)
# Check if the imaginary part is close to zero
assert np.all(np.isclose(np.imag(ifft), 0, atol=1e-8)), 'imaginary values must be close to 0 otherwise something is wrong!'
# grab the final image
img_abs = np.abs(ifft_result).astype(np.uint8)
img_real = ifft_result.real.astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imshow('padded kernel',cv2.normalize(kernel_padded,None,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX))
cv2.imshow('deblurred(img.real)', img_real)
cv2.imshow('deblurred(np.abs(img))', img_abs)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Here are the outputs(note using .real values for image visualization is inferior to the magnitude based version:



Update 2:
Here is the updated version which:

pads the kernel properly according to this answer
images are clipped properly using the real values and not their magnitudes based on the explanations here
used a much lower epsilon and got a much better output
instead of selecting a single channel from the BGR image, I used the grayscale version which resulted in a much more clearer output.(different channels have different brightness, so they lead to different outcomes, using grayscale version removes this discrepancy.

However, playing with epsilon, while results in a better output compared to the previous attempts, it introduces some artifacts/patterns into the final deblurred result which is not indented or wanted.
Is this the best I can hope for, or is there still space for improvements?
The outputs are given at the end:

def add_motion_blur(img, size=31, angle=11):
    kernel = np.zeros((size,size), dtype=np.float32)
    # Set the middle row of the kernel array to be all ones. 
    kernel[size//2,:] = np.ones((size,),dtype=np.float32)
    # Now rotate the kernel
    m = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((size//2, size//2), angle=angle, scale=1.0)
    kernel = cv2.warpAffine(kernel, m, dsize=(size,size))
    kernel /= np.sum(kernel)
    return cv2.filter2D(img, ddepth=-1, kernel=kernel), kernel

img = cv2.imread('./img/peppers.jpg')
img_blurred, kernel = add_motion_blur(img, size=31, angle=60)
# Use the grayscale image instead
img_blurred_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_blurred,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
fft = np.fft.fftn(img_blurred_gray)
# Pad the kernel properly, and then shift it
pad_height = img.shape[0] - kernel.shape[0]
pad_width = img.shape[1] - kernel.shape[1]
pad_top = pad_height // 2
pad_bottom = pad_height - pad_top
pad_left = pad_width // 2
pad_right = pad_width - pad_left
kernel_padded = np.pad(kernel, [(pad_top, pad_bottom), (pad_left, pad_right)], 'constant')
# shift the kernel
kernel_padded = np.fft.ifftshift(kernel_padded)
fft_psf = np.fft.fft2(kernel_padded)
# The normal way doesnt work very well, but after correcting the kernel, it works much better than the previous attempt! 2 as the regularizer/epsilon seems to give somewhat good result compared to other values.
# fft_result = fft/(fft_psf+2)
# Wiener deconvolution works much better, 0.01 seems like a good eps, but it introduces weird artifacts in the image. 
fft_psf_mag = np.conj(fft_psf) / (np.abs(fft_psf)**2 + 0.01)
fft_result = fft * fft_psf_mag
# Get back the image-no need to shift-back the result!
ifft_result = np.fft.ifft2(fft_result)
# Check if the imaginary part is close to zero
assert np.all(np.isclose(np.imag(ifft), 0, atol=1e-8)), 'imaginary values must be close to 0 otherwise something is wrong!'
# Grab the final image
# Clip the values for more accurate visualization
img_real = ifft_result.real.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imshow('padded kernel',cv2.normalize(kernel_padded,None,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX))
cv2.imshow('deblurred(img.real)', img_real)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()




Update 3:
Here is the updated version which:

fixes the artifacts caused by deblurring by expanding the input image followed by cropping the final result to the original image dimension according to the Cris Luengo's explanations here
individual channels are operated on and later aggregated to allow for color image deblurring (Cris Luengo's explanations here).

After these changes, the result look very good. The outputs are given at the end:

def add_motion_blur(img, size=31, angle=11):
    kernel = np.zeros((size,size), dtype=np.float32)
    # Set the middle row of the kernel array to be all ones. 
    kernel[size//2,:] = np.ones((size,),dtype=np.float32)
    # Now rotate the kernel
    m = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((size//2, size//2), angle=angle, scale=1.0)
    kernel = cv2.warpAffine(kernel, m, dsize=(size,size))
    kernel /= np.sum(kernel)
    return cv2.filter2D(img, ddepth=-1, kernel=kernel), kernel

img = cv2.imread('./img/peppers.jpg')
# so lets add 50px padding to each side of our image 
pad=50
img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, pad,pad,pad,pad,borderType=cv2.BORDER_REFLECT)

img_blurred, kernel = add_motion_blur(img,size=31,angle=60)

pad_height = img.shape[0] - kernel.shape[0] 
pad_width = img.shape[1] - kernel.shape[1]
pad_top = (pad_height+1)//2
pad_bottom = pad_height//2
pad_left = (pad_width+1)//2
pad_right = pad_width//2
kernel_padded = np.pad(kernel, [(pad_top, pad_bottom),(pad_left, pad_right)],mode='constant')
kernel_padded = np.fft.fftshift(kernel_padded)
fft_psf = np.fft.fft2(kernel_padded)

# now lets take the fft of our image
ffts = np.fft.fftn(img_blurred)

# weiner deconvolution
eps = 0.01
fft_psf_mag = np.conj(fft_psf)/(np.abs(fft_psf)**2 + eps)
# individually multiply each channel and then aggregate them
fft_result = np.array([ffts[...,i] * fft_psf_mag for i in range(3)]).transpose(1,2,0)

# now lets get back the image.
iffts = np.fft.ifftn(fft_result)

# before we continue, lets makesure the imaginary components are close to zero
assert np.all(np.isclose(iffts.imag, 0, atol=1e-8)), 'imaginary values must be close to zero! or something is worng'

# take the image 
img_deblurred = iffts.real.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
# crop the final image
img_deblurred_cropped = img_deblurred[pad:img.shape[0]-pad, pad:img.shape[1]-pad]

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.imshow('kenel_padded', cv2.normalize(kernel_padded,None,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX))
cv2.imshow('img-blurred', img_blurred)
cv2.imshow('img-deblurred-uncropped', img_deblurred)
cv2.imshow('img-deblurred-cropped', img_deblurred_cropped)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


result:






@CrisLuengo Thanks a lot really appreciate it. I did as you suggested but the output is still pretty bad. also the real components create a much worse image compared to using magnitude, I added both. could this be a sign of something gone wrong? becasue I'd read that to reconstruct the image both components need to be utilized, hence taking the magnitude makes sense, and the real component not being as good could be explained. is this incorrect?

@CrisLuengo Thanks a lot, that indeed fixed it and made it much better. but its still not good, is this the best wiener can achieve or is there something else that Im missing here? Also Could you kindly explain abit more why we needed to shift the kernel? I always thought we only shift for the sake of visualizations! why do we need our kernel to be set at the corners instead of being at the center? is this because of the periodic nature of Fourier conversion?

@CrisLuengo Thanks , I'll give that a try and report back. I really appreciate your kind help by the way

The origin for the FFT is in the top-left corner. Your kernel must be centered around the origin, otherwise it is shifted. Wiener is a simple, linear method. There are many non-linear, iterative algorithms that work much better. But they’re hard to implement. If you want, you can experiment with some of the more popular ones that I implemented in DIPlib: https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/deconvolution.html — see this notebook: https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/examples/python/deconvolution.ipynb

@CrisLuengo Thanks a gazillion times. really appreciate it. updated the result which look really good! I'll look into your last comment asap.  could you also kindly post your  comments (or however you deem it right) as the answer so I can accept it?

@CrisLuengo, alright then, I'll try to wrap things up as an answer. but thank you once again for your immensely helpful and kind comments/helps, really really appreciate it.

@CrisLuengo, while writing the answer I got one more question, If we used fft_psf = np.fft.fftn(kernel, s=fft.shape) this would put the kernel at the top left corner, and this seems to produce the same or very similar result(I cant tell the difference) to our current way of manipulating the kernel, is there any kind of implications here? is this wrong? because our first method of padding the kernel and shifting it, results the kernel to be split in two and to be put to top right corner, and bottom left corner, but the outcome seems identical to me. thanks a lot

@CrisLuengo, Thanks a lot,is it also correct to say:"The kernel should be centered around the zero-frequency component(i.e. top left corner?). Thats why we often see the kernel being padded and shifted so that its center is at the top-left corner. by fft_psf = np.fft.fftn(kernel, s=fft.shape)) kernel is not centered correctly. However, for many images, especially natural images, the high-frequency components
do not contain much energy. Therefore, the incorrect alignment of
the kernel might not have a large impact, and the results could look very similar to the correctly shifted kernel."

For the record, that's ChatGPT generated, just wanted to check if it has a valid point or its pure hallucination!

Thanks a lot. really appreciate your kind help. I learned a lot from you. I posted an answer, I'd appreciate it if you could kindly have a glance and see if the said explanations are correct and.

side note:
Thanks to @Cris Luengo, the issues were identified and corrected. Here is a summary of all of the points addressed in the comment section which lead to the final solution:
Long Answer:
There are several issues at play here, which are as follows:

The Wiener deconvolution algorithm is implemented incorrectly, the correct form needs the multiplication not division:

   # Wiener deconvolution
   fft_psf_mag = np.conj(fft_psf) / (np.abs(fft_psf)**2 + 10)
   fft_result = fft * fft_psf_mag



the +10 component, i.e. epsilon value is too much. it represents 1/snr. when the correction is applied, using a smaller value of epsilon yields a sharper result, the larger the value, the blurrier the outcome. values in the range of 0.01, 0.001 should be good starting points. (remember you can always try using trackbars and watching the changes realtime to get the best results!)

The way the kernel is being padded is wrong. fft_psf = np.fft.fftn(kernel, s=fft.shape) will put the kernel at the top left corner. This doesn't cause any noticeable change in the output though, but the issue is:
"@Cris Luengo:



If you pad only to the right
and bottom, then the kernel is shifted by some small amount from the
true origin. The larger the kernel, the larger this shift is. You
might not have noticed the small shift in the output, but it’s there,
and if you overlay the result and original images you will see it."


note that we're dealing with the spatial domain there (i.e. it’s about the  position of the kernel in the image before applying FFT).

to cut a long story short, the proper way would be to pad the kernel so the kernel sits at the center of the image and then shift it so the kernel sits at the corners of the image, i.e. do :

pad_height = img.shape[0] - kernel.shape[0] 
pad_width = img.shape[1] - kernel.shape[1]
pad_top = (pad_height+1)//2
pad_bottom = pad_height//2
pad_left = (pad_width+1)//2
pad_right = pad_width//2
kernel_padded = np.pad(kernel, [(pad_top, pad_bottom),(pad_left, pad_right)],mode='constant')
kernel_padded = np.fft.fftshift(kernel_padded)
fft_psf = np.fft.fft2(kernel_padded)

Here's how the output looks when the wrong vs the right kernel is used, note the output seems identical at first glance, but when overlayed on the original image, the wrong one reveals its shifted nature!(we can also see artifacts in this case, especially towards the bottom and bottom right corner):

Using fft_psf = np.fft.fftn(kernel, s=fft.shape):



Using the correct padding/shifting :




4.To get rid of the artifacts in the final image, one can expand the image dimensions by padding all 4 sides, running the operation and finally cropping the final deblurred image to the original image size. This way, by avoiding sharp high frequency drop-offs, we avoid the artifacts:(edgetaper can be used to deal with ring artifacts as well. Here's another implementation in C++. The Python implementation is provided below)
pad = 50
img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, pad, pad, pad, pad, borderType=cv2.BORDER_REFLECT)
...
# crop the final image
img_deblurred_cropped = img_deblurred[pad:img.shape[0]-pad, pad:img.shape[1]-pad]

edgetaper in Python:
def edgetaper(img, gamma=5, beta=0.2):
    width,height = img.shape[:2]
    dx = 2 * np.pi / width
    dy = 2 * np.pi / height
    # subtract dx and dy to match original function's range
    x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi-dx, width)
    y = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi-dy, height)
    w1 = 0.5 * (np.tanh((x + gamma / 2) / beta) - np.tanh((x - gamma / 2) / beta))
    w2 = 0.5 * (np.tanh((y + gamma / 2) / beta) - np.tanh((y - gamma / 2) / beta))
    w = np.dot(w2.reshape(-1, 1), w1.reshape(1, -1))    
    if img.ndim>2:
        w = w[:, :, np.newaxis].repeat(img.shape[2], axis=2)
    return cv2.multiply(img.astype(np.float32), w.astype(np.float32)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

Side Notes:

Use the real components instead of their magnitudes, remember to do proper clipping (i.e. clip(0, 255)) before casting to uint8.
from Cris Luengo


Taking the absolute value, though common, is incorrect.  For example,
you might want to apply a filter to an image that contains negative
values,  or apply a filter that produces negative values.  Taking the
absolute value here would create artefacts.  If the output of the
inverse FFT contains imaginary values significantly different from
zero, then there is an error in the way that the filtering kernel was
padded.


To deblur the color image, simply apply the Wiener's deconvolution on each channel separately, then aggregate them. that is :

ffts = np.fft.fftn(img_blurred)
...
fft_psf_mag = np.conj(fft_psf)/(np.abs(fft_psf)**2 + 1/snr)
# individually multiply each channel and then aggregate them
fft_result = np.array([ffts[...,i] * fft_psf_mag for i in range(3)]).transpose(1,2,0)
# now lets get back the image.
iffts = np.fft.ifftn(fft_result)
# clip and crop to get the final image


Always make sure the imaginary components of your final ifft are close to zero, otherwise this means something is wrong!

assert np.all(np.isclose(iffts.imag, 0, atol=1e-8)), 'imaginary values must be close to zero! or something is worng'


Here is the complete code for deblurring color images using Weiner's deconvolution:
def add_motion_blur(img, size=31, angle=11):
    kernel = np.zeros((size,size), dtype=np.float32)
    # Set the middle row of the kernel array to be all ones. 
    kernel[size//2,:] = np.ones((size,),dtype=np.float32)
    # Now rotate the kernel
    m = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((size//2, size//2), angle=angle, scale=1.0)
    kernel = cv2.warpAffine(kernel, m, dsize=(size,size))
    kernel /= np.sum(kernel)
    return cv2.filter2D(img, ddepth=-1, kernel=kernel), kernel

img_org = cv2.imread('./img/peppers.jpg')
# so lets add 50px padding to each side of our image 
pad=50
img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img_org, pad,pad,pad,pad,borderType=cv2.BORDER_REFLECT)

img_blurred, kernel = add_motion_blur(img, size=31, angle=60)

pad_height = img.shape[0] - kernel.shape[0] 
pad_width = img.shape[1] - kernel.shape[1]
pad_top = (pad_height+1)//2
pad_bottom = pad_height//2
pad_left = (pad_width+1)//2
pad_right = pad_width//2
kernel_padded = np.pad(kernel, [(pad_top, pad_bottom),(pad_left, pad_right)],mode='constant')
kernel_padded = np.fft.fftshift(kernel_padded)
fft_psf = np.fft.fft2(kernel_padded)

# now lets take the fft of our image
ffts = np.fft.fftn(img_blurred)

# Weiner deconvolution
# instead of eps, use snr
snr = 100
fft_psf_mag = np.conj(fft_psf)/(np.abs(fft_psf)**2 + 1/snr)
# individually multiply each channel and then aggregate them
fft_result = np.array([ffts[...,i] * fft_psf_mag for i in range(3)]).transpose(1,2,0)

# now lets get back the image.
iffts = np.fft.ifftn(fft_result)

# make sure the imaginary components are close to zero
assert np.all(np.isclose(iffts.imag, 0, atol=1e-8)), 'imaginary values must be close to zero! or something is worng'

# take the image 
img_deblurred = iffts.real.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
# crop the final image
img_deblurred_cropped = img_deblurred[pad:img.shape[0]-pad, pad:img.shape[1]-pad]

# When the right kernel with proper padding and shifting is used, this looks identical to original image, 
# otherwise, you can see one image is shifted, or worse the whole image is ugly/corrupted looking because one uses the wrong kernel!
overlay = cv2.addWeighted(img_org, 0.5, img_deblurred_cropped, 0.5, 0)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.imshow('kenel_padded', cv2.normalize(kernel_padded,None,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX))
cv2.imshow('img-blurred', img_blurred)
cv2.imshow('img-deblurred-uncropped', img_deblurred)
cv2.imshow('img-deblurred-cropped', img_deblurred_cropped)
cv2.imshow('overlay',overlay)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

The outputs:







I'm not so sure about edgetaper being able to remove this artifact! not sure my implementation is wrong or the type of artifact here is different!

Wonderful writeup! On here, people usually just want a solution and then move on. Thank you for actually wanting to understand the details. It’s been a pleasure to help you!

That edgetaper function in MATLAB is odd, I hadn’t seen something like that before. It is common to multiply with a window function before analysis with the FFT to avoid edge effects. But for filtering, padding is usually the way to go.

Thank you very much for your kind words:) I tested the edgetaper and it seems, it doesn't get rid of the artifact per se, it just conceals it! I prefer the method you recommended by a long shot! do these window functions you linked act the same way? i.e. conceal the artifact or get rid of it like the padding trick?

The window functions reduce the effect of the hard transition from one edge of the image to the other (which you get because the FFT imposes a periodic boundary condition). This transition adds lots of frequencies that are not at all related to the signal. When doing frequency analysis, these added frequencies can really break things. Padding doesn't solve that issue, so windowing is the way to go for analysis. Padding basically moves the edge effect further away from your domain, so it helps when filtering. But for analysis it doesn't help at all.

Thanks a lot, that was really good, so basically they are used extensively for frequency analysis, and not so much for what I have been doing here right? I'll look into them as well to build some more understanding. Thank you again for your immensely helpful comments, I loved each and every single one of them.

I've been looking into this edgetaper function in MATLAB. I don't have the image processing toolbox, so can't see the code. And the documentation is really skimpy. But it doesn't do what your Python implementation does. You implemented a typical window function. The edgetaper function in MATLAB does a smoothing with the periodic boundary condition, and then combines the input image and the smoothed image using a window function as weights. This means that only at the edges (where the window function is low) you see the blurred image. That is, it smoothes the edge transition by blurring.

I've posted a question about edgetaper here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/94227/33605

I implemented my version following the C++ version at opencv.org example. I found the edgetapper implementation for octave though which should be close enough: https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/image/ci/default/tree/inst/edgetaper.m
I havent looked at it myself though, just found it and wanted to share it first to get some insight as well

Thanks for that link! I love that comment: “I have no clue what the MATLAB function is doing.”
